# Is there an "offshoot" of model theory that looks at structures over standard models of arithmetic?

Tags: soft-question, model-theory

Is there an "offshoot" of model theory that looks at structures over standard models of arithmetic? Also, what, if anything, do you lose by fixing $\omega$ as the sole cardinal that you're working with (assuming temporarily that we were originally mostly interested in infinite models)?

I was wondering earlier today if we lose anything by restricting model theory to "just" countably infinite structures and came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105125/prove-that-if-two-theories-have-the-same-countably-infinite-models-then-they-ha). The answer to which implies that if we're interested in *infinite models* initially, then, in a certain sense, we can look at just the countably infinite ones to answer questions about whether two theories have the same models.

Then I started wondering about what happens if we pick the standard model of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ as our carrier.

I'm curious what happens if we take our carrier in our structures to be $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of "just" a set, i.e. we look at only $\models_\mathbb{N}$ or $\models_\mathbb{Z}$.

$$ M \models_{\mathbb{N}} T \;\; \textit{if and only if} \;\; \text{$M \models T$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is the carrier of $M$} \;\;\textit{and likewise for $\mathbb{Z}$} $$

One thing that we can now do is compactly describe *structures that happen to be computable*. We could have done this anyway without fixing our carrier, but fixing $\mathbb{N}$ seems like an interesting perspective, at least.

If we take the $V_2$ symbol from [Büchi arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_arithmetic), then we can construct a dense linear order with a  lower bound over $\mathbb{N}$ in the following way:

$$ x \, (\le)\, y \iff V_2(y)\cdot V_2(y) \cdot x \le V_2(x) \cdot V_2(x) \cdot y $$

This is a dense linear order because it is equivalent to comparing the fractions below, which is equivalent to replacing $2$ with $\frac{1}{2}$ in the prime factorization of a number, which hits all the dyadic rationals.

$$ x \,(\le)\, y \iff \frac{x}{V_2^2(x)} \le \frac{y}{V_2^2(y)} \; \textit{as rational numbers} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at a specific carrier structure, as opposed to simply making a choice of cardinality, lets you do two things I can think of:

- We can talk about how *adding* a piece of structure to an existing structure changes its behavior. The relevant term here is **"expansions"** - e.g. which expansions of $(\mathbb{N};+)$ remain decidable?
- We can talk about how *difficult it is to "build"* a given structure from the perspective of another structure. This is where topics **interpretations** (in first-order or some other logic) and **computable structure theory** (in the specific case of $\mathbb{N}$, or occasionally other "computability-flavored" structures like $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$) live.

---

I know much more about the second bulletpoint, so let me mention one foundational result on the topic (being slightly vague in the interest of brevity): the *Ash/Knight/Manasse/Slaman/Chisholm theorem*, proved by the first four authors as one group and independently the fifth author alone. Suppose I have a countable structure $\mathcal{A}$ and some relation $R$ on $\mathcal{A}$. Consider the following questions:

- How difficult is $R$ to define within $\mathcal{A}$?
- If I build an isomorphic copy $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$, what is the computability-theoretic complexity of $\mathcal{B}^R$ (= $\mathcal{B}$'s version of $R$)?

It turns out that these two questions are tightly related. For example, the following are equivalent:

- For every isomorphic copy $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$, the relation $R^\mathcal{B}$ is computably enumerable.
- There is a computable infinitary $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$ such that $\varphi^\mathcal{A}=R$, that is, $R$ is computable infinitary $\Sigma_1$ definable over $\mathcal{A}$.

Essentially, infinitary logic - or more accurately, *computable* infinitary logic appropriately "stratified" - provides a "carrier-set-independent" approach to certain computability-flavored questions.

Comment: Thank you (and congrats on the 200k). I should have expressed this better in my question, but I am also interested in what you "lose" by fixing a cardinality up front and then asking questions in that restricted setting (provided that we were initially interested in infinite models).

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Well, counting the number of models of a theory of a given cardinality is an important topic in model theory. Morley's theorem is a big result here: that a (complete, consistent, no finite models) theory in a countable language is categorical in *some* uncountable cardinality iff it is categorical in *every* uncountable cardinality. Beyond this we have Shelah's whole **classification theory** program. But I wouldn't call this "fixing a cardinality up front," but rather "asking questions about specific cardinalities" - it's not at all limitative.